# Error while compiling the substrate-node-template on windows vscode

Tags: substrate

error: failed to write bytecode to F:\substrate-node-template\substrate-node-template-master\target\release\wbuild\node-template-runtime\target\wasm32-unknown-unknown\release\deps\pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api-927dd9f7f5859937.pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api.a5dcb31e-cgu.0.rcgu.bc: The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZkQv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that Windows systems have a restriction on path length, and sometimes substrate runs into this! **Better to put your build folder closer to your root dir to minimize path length**. More in this issue(https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/185)

it's a dup question, though.